# divs with scrollbars in div with fixed size

Tags: html, css

I basically have a layout like this:

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 150px; width: 200px; background: green">
      <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; background: blue">
        some content <br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content
      </div>
      <div style="overflow: auto; background: red">
        some more content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, I want the second div to fill all remaining height of the parent div and show the scroll bar if more space is needed. How can I achieve this?
Currently, the second div never shows a scroll bar and just uses the space it needs, even if that will exceed the parents total height...

**UPDATE:**
Please test the solution you provide :-)

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? IE7? Only modern ones?

Comment: @thirtydot: IE7 is the oldest I should support. But if that's not possible, I might think about just ignoring IE7 :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Jquery might help

```
<body>
<div style="height: 150px; width: 200px; background: green">
  <div id="c1" style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; background: blue">
    some content <br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
  <div id="c2"style="overflow: auto; background: red">
    some more content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

in document.ready add this

```
 var h1=$('#c1').height();
var h2 = 150-h1;
$('#c2').height(h2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set max-height to the second div as well

```
<body>
<div style="height: 150px; width: 200px; background: green">
  <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; background: blue">
    some content <br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; background: red; max-height: 50px">
    some more content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not helpful. I want the second div to use all available space in the parent div. With this max-height setting it will not use the space of the first div if that is empty.

Comment: In that case use can set max-height to 150 px for the second div

Answer (score 1):

I only know how to do with this using the forthcoming flexbox layout model. This is how you would do it in current versions of Firefox:

```
<div style="height: 150px; width: 200px; display: -moz-box; -moz-box-orient: vertical; background-color: green;">
  <div style="overflow: auto; min-height: 1px; max-height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; min-height: 1px; -moz-box-flex: 1; background-color: red;">
    some more content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content<br/>
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, I need a cross browser solution, only supporting FF is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you set 
    overflow-y: scroll;
and 
    height: auto;
on the child element, you should be able to achieve the scrollbar effect without exceeding the parent element

Comment: This didn't help. It still extends, just with showing a disabled scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this flexibly, but it's possible if you can know/set the height of the original div and then the next two divs.

Here's what I came up with:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:200px; width: 200px; background: green;">
      <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; background: blue">
        some content <br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some content
      </div>
      <div style="overflow: auto; background: red; min-height:100px; max-height:100px;">
        some more content<br/>
        some content<br/>
        some more content<br/>
        some content<br/>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If the original div is `200px` and then the first daughter div is `100px`, the remaining space of the second daughter div will be `100px`. So, if you set the `min-height and max-height` each to `100px`, then the div will fill the remaining space and display a scroll bar if the content is greater than the `max-height`.

I'm sure you wanted an answer that would be flexible, depending upon the size of the original parent div, but I don't think it's that easy in this case.

Comment: The main problem with your approach is not that it doesn't derive the height from the parent, but that it doesn't work as I want it! The second div is not using all available space inside its parent.

Comment: How is it not? If the parent div is 200px, the first daughter div is 100px, then the second daughter div would use the remaining 100px left.

Comment: The second div will use a maximum of 100px, regardless of the height of the first div. Even if that has a height of 0 because it is empty... That's why the first div has a `max-height` and not a `height`.

Comment: Yes, I said that in my answer. I don't think there is a way to do this in pure CSS, especially something that is cross browser.